# Trying to get Python Arcade to work on Ubuntu

Tags: python, arcade

I have installed Python Arcade using

```
pip install arcade
```

which ran successfully.

When trying to run the example code, or even just trying to `import arcade` from the Python command line, I receive an error

```
>>> import arcade
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/brian/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/arcade/__init__.py", line 250, in <module>
    from .joysticks import get_game_controllers
  File "/home/brian/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/arcade/joysticks.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pyglet.input
  File "/home/brian/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyglet/input/__init__.py", line 179, in <module>
    from .evdev import get_devices as evdev_get_devices
  File "/home/brian/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyglet/input/evdev.py", line 509, in <module>
    class EvdevControllerManager(ControllerManager, XlibSelectDevice):
  File "/home/brian/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyglet/input/evdev.py", line 583, in EvdevControllerManager
    def get_controllers(self) -> list[Controller]:
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
>>>
```

Python version is 3.8.10, and OS is Ubuntu 20.04, but I can't get past this error.

Comment: Thanks - the page with installation instructions just says "The Arcade library is Python 3.7+ only." , so I thought I would be OK.

Comment: That's a bug in `pyglet` introduced recently and fix in [Github](https://github.com/pyglet/pyglet/blame/master/pyglet/input/evdev.py#L585) already. Try to install an older version of `pyglet`!

Comment: Arcade 2.6.15 was released to resolve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the response from @mkrieger1, and the error being shown, I took the following steps:

`vim /home/brian/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyglet/input/evdev.py`

added a line below the other `import` sections at the top

`import typing`

then went to line 583 (now 584 due to adding above), and changed

`def get_controllers(self) -> list[Controller]:`

to

`def get_controllers(self) -> typing.List[Controller]:`

and the example programs are now working.

If anyone else is in the same situation, then hopefully this is a quick fix to try.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in the pyglet library: https://github.com/pyglet/pyglet/issues/614

The code uses `list[Controller]` which requires Python 3.9 (see [PEP 585](https://peps.python.org/pep-0585/)).

The line was introduced to pyglet in [commit 3c2c7de](https://github.com/pyglet/pyglet/commit/3c2c7de4a42cd0796a38b1557b5e2322b2433a59) and was fixed in [commit 63341c4](https://github.com/pyglet/pyglet/commit/63341c421ba2dcb55546801d02d98215bf4b4c83) (10 days ago as of today), which changes it to `List[Controller]` (where `List` is imported from the standard `typing` module).